# Hash Map implementing linked list via separate chaining (int key, LinkedList value) is this right?

Tags: java

Trying to make a text reader when passed a document it reads in words per line and can return all words per line as well as search for specific words. No interface yet made just working on functionality. I was wondering what data structure would be the best performance wise for this.
Also what time complexity would this give in the worst case for the below solution?
This is what i have tried thus far using java:

```
package main;
import lib.Node;import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSInput;
import java.util.HashMap;
import lib.LinkedList;

public class ListApp {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    HashMap<Integer, LinkedList> a = new HashMap<Integer, LinkedList>();

        Node n5 = new Node("orange", null);
        Node n4 = new Node("green", null);
        Node n3 = new Node("orange", n4);
        Node n2 = new Node("blue", n3);
        Node n1 = new Node("red", n2);

        Node a2 = new Node("sda", null);
        Node a1 = new Node("yellows", a2);
        Node a7 = new Node("", null);

        a.put(1, new LinkedList(n1));
        a.get(1).insertAfter(n5, n4);
        a.put(2, new LinkedList(n1));
        a.put(3, new LinkedList(n5));

        String lookingFor;
        int count = 0;
        lookingFor = "orange";
        for (int line = 1; line <= 1; line++) {
        for(Node current = a.get(line).getHead(); current != null; current = current.next()) {
            if (current.getItem() == lookingFor) {
              count += 1;
              System.out.println("found on Line: " + line + ", item: " + current.getItem());
            } 
          }
        }
        System.out.println("There is " + count + " " + lookingFor);

        System.out.println(a.get(4));// This is just for testing

  }
}
```